# parsley custom validator not responding on First click

Tags: javascript, parsley.js, parsley

I am trying to do luhn check validation for a field which should be validated after parsley.validate()  method.

Please find my below code,

`<input type="text" maxlength="19"
                                data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-length="[13,19]"
                                data-parsley-type="digits"
                                data-parsley-required-message="Enter Credit card number"
                                data-parsley-type-message="Incorrect card number"
                                data-parsley-minlength-message="Incorrect card number"
                                data-parsley-maxlength-message="Incorrect card number" 
                                    id="creditCardNumber" name="CardNumber" data-parsley-luhn="true" required>`

`if($("#form").parsley().validate()){
            //add the card validator:
               window.Parsley.addValidator('luhn',{
              validateNumber: function (value) {
                    val = value.replace(/[ -]/g, '');
                    var digit, n, sum, _j, _len1, _ref2;
                    sum = 0;
                    _ref2 = val.split('').reverse();
                    for (n = _j = 0, _len1 = _ref2.length; _j < _len1; n = ++_j) {
                        digit = _ref2[n];
                        digit = +digit;
                        if (n % 2) {
                            digit *= 2;
                            if (digit < 10) {
                                sum += digit;
                            } else {
                                sum += digit - 9;
                            }
                        } else {
                            sum += digit;
                        }
                    }
                    if(sum % 10 === 0){
                          return  true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                        }
                }
                });
        }`

Validation works only when I click the submit button second time. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `window.Parsley.addValidator` once, at init time.

BTW, there's a [`lunh` validator already coded for you](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/extra/validator/luhn.js)